# Are users downvoting valid questions simply because they think the question is stupid?

Tags: discussion, questions

I posted this question:
[How to Require All Struct or Class Members to Be Assigned by Initiailzer in C Sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866071/how-to-require-all-struct-or-class-members-to-be-assigned-by-initializer-c-shar)

And it was immediately downvoted 4 times. From the comments, I get the impression that people simply hold personal opinions that the question is stupid.

But as far as I can tell, my question follows the rules for acceptable questions on SO.  So technically it shouldn't be downvoted right?

In the case of my question, I basically asked "Is there a way to do x?". A valid answer would be "No. It's not possible."  Instead people attacked the question itself in the comments.

My personal experience on here has been that a lot of users tend to downvote things just because they don't like what's being asked or it makes them uncomfortable.

Am I wrong about this?

Answer (score 10):

"Usefulness" is a metric used for voting.  You can see the tooltip when you hover over the downvote button.

If people don't believe that your question is particularly *useful*, then it's vulnerable to downvotes.

Usefulness includes, but isn't limited to:

- Practicality
- Feasibility
- Plausibility
- Straightforwardness
- Intent

If you don't want your question to be downvoted since it's perceived not to be useful, then be sure that your question meets at least a handful of these criterion.  While I don't know C#, some of the comments lead me to believe that your question lacks feasibility and practicality, and as such, is being voted on accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

You wanted to know how to do a thing, but you already knew of a way to do exactly the thing that you want, simply, easily, and effectively, and mentioned that solution in the question.  You then just stated that you didn't want to use it, but not why.

At that point it's *not* really a valid question, no.  You know the answer to your question, you just...don't want to use it.  If you explained *why* you couldn't use the answer you had stated, and they were reasonable reasons, then you could have had a useful question in there for someone to answer.  But as it is, your question *contains the answer in the question*, so there's nothing for anyone to answer, hence no one tried to post an answer.

Comment: Hmmm.  That makes sense.  Next time I'll try to do a better job of explaining why the solution I described isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JamesHoux you wanted a way of inserting a constructor template that has parameters and assignments that initialize all, (current), data members?  Would you expect that kept up-to-date as members are added/edited/deleted?   See - what you seem to want is not clearly defined?